# Regular expression to match 12-hour time

Tags: regex

I keep getting an error for this regular expression:

```
^((([1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])(0|5)/s(A|P)M)$
```

It's supposed to be for a time that ends in 0 or 5.  So here are some that should work:

- 1:25 PM
- 11:00 AM
- 9:55 PM

But I keep getting this error message:

Internal error matching pattern `'^((([1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])(0|5)/s(A|P)M)$'` against value `'1:00 PM'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What regex engine?  You may want \\( instead of (, but it depends on which regex syntax you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use \s not /s

Answer (score 7):

\s, not /s. But you should also make it \s+ since people insert many spaces by accident. Probably wouldn't be a bad idea to begin and end the regex with \s* too. And what if someone puts in a time 09:50? include 0 in that first group.

Answer (score 5):

I think instead of '/s', you're wanting '\s', aren't you?